# Minio Large File Upload C# SDK

Tags: asp.net-core, upload, storage, multipart, minio

What is the best practice for uploading large files with Minio C# .Net Core SDK? There is no method I could find to upload chunked files. Only thing I could find is PutObjectAsync method and it uploads files above 5mb in parts. But what about a stream I send over HTTP Post?